# Im getting null pointer exception in my object array

Tags: java, arrays

So, I'm creating an array of seats on an airplane, with the traits **seat number**, **seat type**, and **passenger**.

First off..here is my code making the seat object in a separate class:

```
public class Seat {

private int seatNumber;
private String passenger;
private String seatType;

public Seat(int seatNumber, String seatType, String passenger){
    seatNumber=this.seatNumber;
    seatType=this.seatType;
    passenger=this.passenger;
}
public int getSeatNumber() {
    return seatNumber;
}

public String getPassenger() {
    return passenger;
}

public String getSeatType() {
    return seatType;
}
```

In my main class I have:

```
    import javax.swing.*;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.List;
    import java.util.*;

    public class AirplaneReservation {
public static Seat []seatList= new Seat[12];


public void SeatList(){
    for (int i=0; i<seatList.length; i++){
        seatList[i]= new Seat(i, null, null);
    }

    Seat seat1 = new Seat(1, "First Class", "Collins");
    seatList[0]=seat1;
    Seat seat2 = new Seat(2, "First Class", "null");
    seatList[1]=seat2;
    Seat seat3 = new Seat(3, "First Class", "Faivre");
    seatList[2]=seat3;
    Seat seat4 = new Seat(4, "First Class", "Kinnard");
    seatList[3]=seat4;;
    Seat seat5 = new Seat(5, "Coach", "null");
    seatList[4]=seat5;
    Seat seat6 = new Seat(6, "Coach", "null");
    seatList[5]=seat6;
    Seat seat7 = new Seat(7, "Coach", "Morgans");
    seatList[6]=seat7;
    Seat seat8 = new Seat(8, "Coach", "Rohan");
    seatList[7]=seat8;
    Seat seat9 = new Seat(9, "Coach", "Shatrov");
    seatList[8]=seat9;
    Seat seat10 = new Seat(10, "Coach", "Sword");
    seatList[9]=seat10;
    Seat seat11 = new Seat(11, "Coach", "null");
    seatList[10]=seat11;
    Seat seat12 = new Seat(12, "Coach", "Tuckness");
    seatList[11]=seat12;
}

public static void main (String [] args){

    System.out.println("Seat\tPassenger");
    System.out.println(seatList[0].getSeatNumber());
```

I found that many people were having the problem of not making the arrays with non-null objects, but when I try the block of code that I think does that, I still get a null pointer exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at AirplaneReservation.main(AirplaneReservation.java:45)
```

What am I missing to not make those objects null?

Comment: System.out.println(seatList[0].getSeatNumber());

Comment: remove for (int i=0; i<seatList.length; i++){
        seatList[i]= new Seat(i, null, null);
    } doesnt make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main() method is accessing the static seatList field, which has not been populated (SeatList() has not been called yet).

seatList should probably be made non-static, and accessed via a getter method, to enforce that the object is fully initialized before it's used.

or make SeatList() static and call it from a static initializer to ensure that it's called.

Comment: Okay, so I changed seatList to non static, and added 

 public Seat[] getSeatList() {
  return seatList;
 }

Would I then want to change it to static in order for it to be accessed/how would I go about accessing seatList[0]?

Comment: You can instantiate a new SeatList() in your main method, something like SeatList sl = new SeatList(); Seat seat = sl.getSeatList()[0];

Comment: Well, after adding "SeatList();" in my main function, I'm no longer having nullpointerexceptions, but when I go to print the list, all seat numbers and passengers are 0 and null respectively.  If you have the answer, fantastic, butI think that gets into the nitty gritty of how I have my program set up though. Thank you so much for your help thus far.

Answer (score 0):

It's a null pointer exception, because you forgot to call the function to add Seats to the array. As it is now, you define an array of Seats but add nothing to it, so by default, everything is null.

Remember to call SeatList() in the main method.